# Mongoid: How to create separate database for every user in Rails 3.2

Tags: mongodb, database-design, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid

I am working on a new Rails application with MongoDB. Here I want to create a separate database for every user who registers into the application.

I am trying to create the database like this, here is my `mongoid.yml` configuration:

```
staging:
  host: localhost
  database: mongoid_<%= @user.username%>
```

Please help me to create separate database for every user in MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer you to use separate collections for each registered user instead of separate dbs. But if you insist so use Moped session explained in this link http://mongoid.org/en/moped/docs/driver.html#behaviour